# Equivalent of CEF's OnLoadingStateChange in WebView2

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control, chromium-embedded, webview2

In my WPF application that hosts the WebView2 control, I want to
keep a track on the loading state of my browser just like how
'OnloadingStateChange' does in CEF.

How can i achieve the same thing in WebView2 ?

Answer (score 3):

The [CoreWebView2.NavigationStarting event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/dotnet/0-9-628/microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2#navigationstarting) is dispatched before the top level document of the WebView2 navigates to a new URI and [CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/dotnet/0-9-628/microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2#navigationcompleted) is dispatched after that navigation fails or the document loads. Here's info on [WebView2 navigation events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/navigation-events).

From the WPF WebView2 control you can use the CoreWebView2 property to find all navigation events. The CoreWebView2 property is available [after the WebView2 is initialized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/wpf/0-9-515/microsoft-web-webview2-wpf-webview2).

[image: Diagram of WebView2 navigation event state diagram.]